# Validity of SIP ACK response to SIP 200 OK message

Tags: sip

We are sending a sip call to one of our partner. They are sending us “Record-Route” and “Contact” headers within 200 OK message. Our side is sending ACK to the IP address mentioned in the Record-Route but it is replacing the “Contact” header with “Route” header and other side is not honoring our ACK and sending us repeated 200 OK which results into call disconnection.

I am not sure if we are violating any SIP RFC by changing "Contact" header to "Route" while maintaining the contents of the header. Can anyone shed a light on it?

**Here is the 200 OK from partner side:**

```
SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100;received=100.100.100.100;rport=5060
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
Contact: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: ACK, INVITE, BYE, CANCEL
Content-Type: application/sdp
Server: YATE/3.0.0
Content-Length: 195

v=0
o=yate 1441225325 1441225325 IN IP4 201.201.201.30
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 201.201.201.30
t=0 0
m=audio 19305 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv
```

**Here is our ACK to 200 OK message:**

```
ACK sip:200.200.200.2:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 ACK
Max-Forwards: 70
Route: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
Content-Length: 0
```

**Here is the Entire SIP dialog:**

```
INVITE sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
Contact: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>
User-Agent: Excel_CSP/84.11.34
Supported: timer
Session-Expires: 3660
Min-SE: 300
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Max-Forwards: 70
Content-Type: application/sdp
Content-Length: 144

v=0
o=sip 0 0 IN IP4 100.100.100.100
s=SIP_Call
c=IN IP4 100.100.100.230
t=0 0
m=audio 46750 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000

SIP/2.0 100 Trying
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100;received=100.100.100.100;rport=5060
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Server: YATE/3.0.0
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100;received=100.100.100.100;rport=5060
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
Contact: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: ACK, INVITE, BYE, CANCEL
Server: YATE/3.0.0
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100;received=100.100.100.100;rport=5060
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
Contact: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: ACK, INVITE, BYE, CANCEL
Content-Type: application/sdp
Server: YATE/3.0.0
Content-Length: 195

v=0
o=yate 1441225325 1441225325 IN IP4 201.201.201.30
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 201.201.201.30
t=0 0
m=audio 19305 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv

ACK sip:200.200.200.2:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 ACK
Max-Forwards: 70
Route: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100;received=100.100.100.100;rport=5060
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
Contact: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: ACK, INVITE, BYE, CANCEL
Content-Type: application/sdp
Server: YATE/3.0.0
Content-Length: 195

v=0
o=yate 1441225325 1441225325 IN IP4 201.201.201.30
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 201.201.201.30
t=0 0
m=audio 19305 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv
ACK sip:200.200.200.2:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 ACK
Max-Forwards: 70
Route: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100;received=100.100.100.100;rport=5060
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
Contact: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: ACK, INVITE, BYE, CANCEL
Content-Type: application/sdp
Server: YATE/3.0.0
Content-Length: 195

v=0
o=yate 1441225325 1441225325 IN IP4 201.201.201.30
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 201.201.201.30
t=0 0
m=audio 19305 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv
ACK sip:200.200.200.2:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 ACK
Max-Forwards: 70
Route: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100;received=100.100.100.100;rport=5060
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
Contact: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: ACK, INVITE, BYE, CANCEL
Content-Type: application/sdp
Server: YATE/3.0.0
Content-Length: 195

v=0
o=yate 1441225325 1441225325 IN IP4 201.201.201.30
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 201.201.201.30
t=0 0
m=audio 19305 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv
ACK sip:200.200.200.2:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 ACK
Max-Forwards: 70
Route: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100;received=100.100.100.100;rport=5060
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
Contact: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: ACK, INVITE, BYE, CANCEL
Content-Type: application/sdp
Server: YATE/3.0.0
Content-Length: 195

v=0
o=yate 1441225325 1441225325 IN IP4 201.201.201.30
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 201.201.201.30
t=0 0
m=audio 19305 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv
ACK sip:200.200.200.2:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 ACK
Max-Forwards: 70
Route: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 200 OK
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100;received=100.100.100.100;rport=5060
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
Contact: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Allow: ACK, INVITE, BYE, CANCEL
Content-Type: application/sdp
Server: YATE/3.0.0
Content-Length: 195

v=0
o=yate 1441225325 1441225325 IN IP4 201.201.201.30
s=SIP Call
c=IN IP4 201.201.201.30
t=0 0
m=audio 19305 RTP/AVP 0 101
a=rtpmap:0 PCMU/8000
a=rtpmap:101 telephone-event/8000
a=sendrecv


ACK sip:200.200.200.2:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 100.100.100.100
To: +200<sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
From: +100<sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 1 ACK
Max-Forwards: 70
Route: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
Content-Length: 0

BYE sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 200.200.200.2:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---baf0e608a3be462e3d9534147efb1150;rport
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.10.10.135:7654;rport=7654;branch=z9hG4bK962836463;received=10.10.10.135
Max-Forwards: 69
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
To: <sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
From: <sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 95618 BYE
Allow: ACK, INVITE, BYE, CANCEL
User-Agent: YATE/3.0.0
Reason: SIP;cause=408;text="Request Timeout"
Content-Length: 0

SIP/2.0 200 OK 
To: <sip:+100@100.100.100.100:5060>;tag=4244235125227
From: <sip:+200@200.200.200.2:5060>;tag=784054843
Call-ID: CANTATA21.1a8.1200679.50@100.100.100.100
CSeq: 95618 BYE
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 200.200.200.2:5060;branch=z9hG4bK-524287-1---baf0e608a3be462e3d9534147efb1150;rport
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 10.10.10.135:7654;rport=7654;branch=z9hG4bK962836463;received=10.10.10.135
User-Agent: Excel_CSP/84.11.34
Content-Length: 0
```

IP addresses and SIP TO/FROM information has been manually updated to conceal the original identity.

I have gone through RFC 3261 I found following on page # 161. I am not sure, how to read the following table. Does it mean that Contact header is not applicable in ACK to 2xx messages?

```
Header field          where   proxy ACK BYE CAN INV OPT REG
      ___________________________________________________________
      Contact          2xx           -   -    -   m   o   o
```

Answer (score 4):

The 200 Ok contains:

```
Record-Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
Contact: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
```

Your application doesn't look to understand the meaning of "lr" parameter: the "loose routing" parameter introduced in rfc3261. It's not even compatible with the initial rfc2543.

If your app was only compatible with rfc2543, the ACK would contains the exact message you have, but with the additionnal "lr" parameter. This would indicate to the server that the order is rfc2543, and in theory, the server would understand and re-order: (rfc3261, Section 16.6, Step 6. Postprocess routing information)

```
ACK sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr SIP/2.0
Route: <sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654>
```

However, a correct message should be compliant with latest rfc3261, and thus your app has to generate the following SIP message:

```
ACK sip:+100@10.10.10.135:7654 SIP/2.0
Route: <sip:200.200.200.2:5060;lr>
```

The whole issue is about wrong handling of the "lr" parameter in your application! The solution is to fix the missing "lr" and make sure the order is accurate according to rfc3261.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you've stripped out some parts of the SIP headers when you posted your question. Most of the Via headers are missing the mandatory branches parameter which is particularly crucial in INVITE transaction processing.

Aside from the problem AymericM hash highlighted with regards the Contact and Route headers you "could" also have another problem with regards the Via header branch parameter in your ACK request. Specifically you should take a look at Chapters [13.2.2.4 2xx Responses](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-13.2.2.4) and [17.1.1.3 Construction of the ACK Request](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-17.1.1.3) for details on how ACK requests should be constructed.

The key is that the ACK request must start a NEW transaction when acknowledging a non 2xx failure response. When acknowledging a 2xx response the ACK request must be an in-transaction request and use the same header fields, including the Via header branch parameter, as the original INVITE request.

Construction of ACK requests is one of the biggest gotchas in SIP.